# img.toDataURL() is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

Hello I'm making a collaborative whiteboard. I want to drag and drop images on canvas. These should also be visible to other clients connected to the server.

This is the code for putting it in toDataUrl():

```js
img = document.getElementById("gif")
              
var base64ImageData = img.toDataURL("image/png");
root.socket.emit("board-data", base64ImageData);
```

This is the html code for draggable image:

```html
<h4>Select picture!</h4>
{this.state.images.map(image => (
    <div className="dragImg">
        <img id="gif" classnName="img" src={image.image} width='200px' height='100px'/>
    </div>
))}
                        
<div id="dropHere">
    <canvas className="board" id="board" color={this.state.color} size={this.state.size}></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, why do you think `img.toDataURL` would be a function?

Comment: Hi There. Try posting a minimum reproducible sample using http://codesandbox.io/.

Comment: @Teemu Because it worked for this piece of code: ```root.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                var base64ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                root.socket.emit("canvas-data", base64ImageData);
            }, 1000)``` but for my image it does not work

Comment: The former is an image (no toDataURL) and the latter is a canvas (providing toDataURL)

Comment: `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` function on canvas element not on `<img>` element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: @RahulKumar so for image its basically not needed to convert it right? I can just emit the image in socket?

Comment: try using canvas id instead of img